# Is BT (begin text) and ET (end text) always on its own line?

Tags: pdf

I am currently trying to modify text strings in a PDF. I do so by uncompressing the PDF with `pdftk`, parsing the text with RegEx and then substituting the strings.

I search single text blocks by looking for `BT` and `ET` on its own line. This works for the sample PDF I used. I am, however, not sure if PDF requires `BT` and `ET` to be on its own line. Could somebody clarify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is BT (begin text) and ET (end text) always on its own line?

No, that's only pretty print. Unless a content stream contains comments, you can usually put it completely on a single line.

Comment: Ok, so do you know if at least `pdftk` guarantees that BT / ET is on its own line? Or is there a simple RegEx / method which finds the lines in the file where text blocks are?

Comment: If I remember correctly, pdftk is based on an old version of iText. IText, when adding new content stream instructions, usually did put a single instruction on each line. But when copying existing content, it leaves that content as is.